# Select an option from dropdown box using DOMCrawler in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I am using DOMCrawler in PHP. I have the HTML below.
I need to be able to select the option "Text1", and submit the form. I have the following code but I can't seem to make it work... What am I doing wrong?

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://myURL');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Text1')->form();   
$crawler2 = $client->submit($form);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="something.php" name="frmOpcion" id="frmOpcion" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<select name="cmbOpcion" id="cmbOpcion" class="textoCmb">
<option value="a">Text1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="b">Text2</option>
</select>

<input type="image" name="imgOpcion" id="imgOpcion" alt="Send" title="Send" src="goTo.gif">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#forms) gives this example:

```
// Select an option or a radio
$form['country']->select('France');
```

To adapt the example to your situation, first select the form. Note that `selectButton()` is for buttons and inputs, not select controls:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('imgOpcion');
```

Next, set the value of the select:

```
$form->select('Text1');
```

Finally, submit the form:

```
$client->submit($form)
```

Comment: $form->select() is used to select by option value not by option text